# InstallShield 2012 Deploying dll from temporary asp.net folder

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I have an InstallShield Spring 2012 project in my solution. I added to it the project output from a Windows Service project in my solution.  This windows service project references a library project that is also in the solution.  This same library project is referenced by an ASP.Net MVC web project that is in the same solution.

Now, when the install from the generated setup.exe is run, it runs fine without any problem.  It installs to the expected destination folder, and I can see the exe for the windows service as well as the dll of the libary project.

EXCEPT: the library project datetime stamp is not the latest build - it was about a month old!  I pulled my hair out trying to figure out where it is getting this older version dll from.  I eventually found that it is getting it in the Temporary ASP.Net files folder.  I immediately deleted the contents of this folder and built the setup project again.

This time it worked.  But sure enough, after making more changes to the library project, and rebuilding the setup exe, the deployed exe is still the non-latest one that it gets from the Temporary ASP.Net files folder.

Why on earth would it be doing this?  Have I missed a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The contents from project output groups are dictated by the project providing the list of files; if it provides useless information, one cannot turn that into good information. If you know where the files you need to include are being built, skip the project output group reference, and add the files directly to your InstallShield project.

Answer (score 0):

Finally .. I was frustrated and looking for a solution for almost a week.

I cant understand why , but deleting the temp asp.net folder does work, in fixing the references especially if you have recently upgraded to enterprise library 6.0 and are using TFS .

Two thumbs Up to Shawn's answer.